# Populate Javascript OptionArray with mysql table data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

```
<!----HERE IS ALL MY CODE--->
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","theswapt_Swapper","$1Swapper","theswapt_TheSwap2Shop");
                    // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    };
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM class_swap_categories WHERE parent='2093'");

function whileloop($result2) {
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {echo '"' . $row1['id'] . '|' . $row1['catname'] . '"' . ',';};
};
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function populate(s1,s2){
var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
s2.innerHTML = "";
if(s1.value == "2093"){
    var optionArray = [<?php echo whileloop($result2);?>];
} else if(s1.value == "1843"){
    var optionArray = ["|","avenger|Avenger","challenger|Challenger","charger|Charger"];
} else if(s1.value == "Ford"){
    var optionArray = ["|","mustang|Mustang","shelby|Shelby"];
}
for(var option in optionArray){
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
}
}
</script>

<form method="post">


Choose Category:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')" style="height: 40px; margin:     5px; width: 100%; max-width: 250px; color: #00B8FF;">
<option value=""></option>
<?php

                    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM class_swap_categories WHERE parent='0'");

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                    echo '<option value="' .$row['id']. '">' .$row['catname']. '</option>'; 

                    };

                  ?>
</select>
Choose Style:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2" style="height: 40px; margin: 5px; width: 100%; max-width: 250px;    color: #00B8FF;"></select>

</form>
```

my issue is that I can't get the first 2093 to load correctly, no matter what i do, the php while statement adds a new line to the end of the statement and the javascript array looks like this when I run it. Instead of the 1843 option thats displayed correctly because it's not dynamic. Please help.

```
 if(s1.value == "2093"){
    var optionArray = ["2124| Pants & Jeans
 ","2118| Swim
 ","2112| Tanks & Tees
 ","2106| Dress Shirts
 ","2100| Polos & Casual Shirts
 ","2094| Bundled Outfit(s)
 ","2149| Shorts
 ","2157| Hoodies & Sweatshirts
 ","2163| Sweaters & Cardigans
 ","2169| Jackets & Sports Coats
 ","2175| Suits & Suit Separates
 ","2181| Active Wear
 ","2187| Lounge Wear & Robes
 ",];
} else if(s1.value == "1843"){
    var optionArray = ["|","avenger|Avenger","challenger|Challenger","charger|Charger"];
} else if(s1.value == "Ford"){
    var optionArray = ["|","mustang|Mustang","shelby|Shelby"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new line is because their is a comma <,> at the end of the output of the function **whileloop**, use the function below to remove it:

```
function whileloop($result2) {
$finalOpt = "";
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) 
{
if($finalOpt=="")
    $finalOpt = $finalOpt.'"' . $row1['id'] . '|' . $row1['catname'] . '"';
else
    $finalOpt = $finalOpt.',"' . $row1['id'] . '|' . $row1['catname'] . '"';
};
```

And from your question i am not getting what other problems you are facing, explain them.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but that isn't the reason. I tried your example and mine with the comma removed at the end and both returned the same output as the example i provided. This is crazy, i've tried it a million ways, i know it's something stupid. Thanks again.